# Spring Cloud DataFlow

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am creating an stream where the source(producer) is producing around 12 million records in around 8 mins, the transformer (consumer) starts consuming them ok, but at some point around 4 mins into it the following shows in the log of the app, and it stops receiving anything past this point:

```
2018-07-11 21:59:18,811 24043857 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | cdSomeApp] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=cdSomeApp] Marking the coordinator 10.16.17.59:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) dead
2018-07-11 21:59:18,815 24043861 [cdSomeApp.cd-source.container-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=cdSomeApp] Discovered group coordinator 10.16.17.59:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2018-07-11 21:59:18,815 24043861 [cdSomeApp.cd-source.container-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=cdSomeApp] Marking the coordinator 10.16.17.59:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) dead
2018-07-11 21:59:18,930 24043976 [cdSomeApp.cd-source.container-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=cdSomeApp] Discovered group coordinator 10.16.17.59:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
2018-07-11 21:59:18,933 24043979 [cdSomeApp.cd-source.container-0-C-1] ERROR o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=cdSomeApp] Offset commit failed on partition cdSomeApp.cd-source-0 at offset 140802810: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
2018-07-11 21:59:18,937 24043983 [cdSomeApp.cd-source.container-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: null
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:787)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:735)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:814)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:794)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:507)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:353)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:268)
```

From what I can see the default values for kafka configuration should work ok, but if anybody knows better, please advice?

thanks!

Comment: The app is using sprng boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: Also spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka and spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors version 2.0.0.RELEASE. The kafka install is at kafka_2.11-1.1.0

Comment: I ran again, changing the default kafka 1.0 config from the default, same results, here are the values changed:

Comment: request.timeout.ms: 18300000
session.timeout.ms: 7200000 
max.poll.records: 500 
heartbeat.interval.ms: 1800000

Answer (score 0):

The report doesn't include any version information. It'd be good if the post is edited with Spring Cloud Stream (App Starters version - which bit.ly url was used?), Spring Boot, SCDF, and Kafka broker versions in use.

All that said, we have had a similar report in Spring Cloud Stream's Chelsea release-train against Kafka 0.9. Here are some [details and the outcome](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/154).

If you're on this version combination, you'd have to upgrade to Ditmars (1.3.x) or the latest Elmhurst (2.0.x) release. We have the latest bit.ly against these versions in the [App Starters project site](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#stream-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-), too.

Comment: as far as I know, I am using the latest relase version of everything

Comment: A rebalance implies the transformer is taking more than 5 minutes to process the records retrieved by the poll. Try reducing `max.poll.records` and/or increasing `max.poll.interval.ms`.